# Exact match of string in pandas python

Tags: regex, excel, python-2.7, pandas

I have a column in data frame which ex df:

```
  A
0 Good to 1. Good communication EI : tathagata.kar@ae.com
1 SAP ECC Project System  EI: ram.vaddadi@ae.com
2 EI : ravikumar.swarna  Role:SSE  Minimum Skill
```

I have a list of of strings

```
ls=['tathagata.kar@ae.com','a.kar@ae.com']
```

Now if i want to filter out

```
for i in range(len(ls)):
   df1=df[df['A'].str.contains(ls[i])
        if len(df1.columns!=0):
            print ls[i]
```

I get the output

```
tathagata.kar@ae.com 
a.kar@ae.com
```

But I need only `tathagata.kar@ae.com`

How Can It be achieved?
As you can see I've tried **str.contains** But I need something for extact match

Comment: Add a space in front of the emailadresses (so in `ls`)? Because Python is right, `a.kar@ae.com` is in the first item of your df

Comment: Yes, I agree. I tried doing different things like this 
**str.contains(r'(?:\s|^)%s(?:\s|$)'%ls[i])**

Where (Only the word between ^ (Denotes space) and $(Denotes end of string) Needs to be printed.
But my result was empty dataframe.

Comment: use a regex r'\s\w+'+ls[i], this regex matches a whitespace, then characters and then your string. If this helps ill update it as an answer

Comment: @IsaacDj I tried using **str.contains(r'\s\w+'+ls[i])** 
But I got **_a.kar@ae.com_** as my output rather than vice versa.

Comment: try parsing the ls[i], in the regex case it needs to have the periods backslashed:
r'\s\w+'+ls[i].replace('.',r'\.')

Answer (score 3):

You could simply use ==

```
string_a == string_b
```

It should return True if the two strings are equal. But this does not solve your issue.

**Edit 2:** You should use len(df1.index) instead of len(df1.columns). Indeed, len(df1.columns) will give you the number of columns, and not the number of rows.

**Edit 3:** After reading your second post, I've understood your problem. The solution you propose could lead to some errors.
For instance, if you have:

```
ls=['tathagata.kar@ae.com','a.kar@ae.com', 'tathagata.kar@ae.co']
```

the first and the third element will match str.contains(r'(?:\s|^|Ei:|EI:|EI-)'+ls[i])
And this is an unwanted behaviour.

You could add a check on the end of the string: str.contains(r'(?:\s|^|Ei:|EI:|EI-)'+ls[i]+r'(?:\s|$)')

Like this:

```
for i in range(len(ls)):
  df1 = df[df['A'].str.contains(r'(?:\s|^|Ei:|EI:|EI-)'+ls[i]+r'(?:\s|$)')]
  if len(df1.index != 0):
      print (ls[i])
```

(Remove parenthesis in the "print" if you use python 2.7)

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I didn't understand it. Could you please show it in my examplle?

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use:

```
df1 = df[df['A'].[str.match][1](ls[i])
```

It's the equivalent of regex match.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the help. But seems like I found a solution that is working as of now.

Must use **str.contains(r'(?:\s|^|Ei:|EI:|EI-)'+ls[i])** 
This seems to solve the problem.

Although thanks to @IsaacDj for his help.

Comment: And what happened when you used str.match instead of that complex regex?

Comment: It didn't return any value, tried them all mate. 
I am looking for a simpler solution. Can you help me with one?

Comment: If there is a space char before all strings to find, like in your sample data, maybe you could simplify a little your regex: str.contains(' '+ls[i]+r'(?:\s|$)')